# Get 'Zone already loaded' error in Rails + webpack + angular 2 initial setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I used following specifications.

1) rails 5.1.3

2) ruby 2.4.1

3) rail with webpacker

4) Angular 4.3.4 with webpacker (Typescript)

I create new rail app using command `rails new my-rails-app --webpack-angular`.

**Folder structure**

[image]

After that, as per instruction under `app/javascript/packs/application.js` and `app/javascript/packs/hello_angular.js`,  I added `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in `application.html.erb` to `head` tag next after `javascript_include_tag`.

Also add below markup to body tag in layout `application.html.erb`

```
// <hello-angular>Loading...</hello-angular>
//
// <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_angular' %>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularOnRailsWithWebpack</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <hello-angular>Loading...</hello-angular>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_angular' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now create new scaffolding by running `rails g scafolld post title:string desc:text` and set post index page as root path

Now run rails server by running `rails s` and webpack server by running `./bin/webpack-dev-server`

Works fine.

But When I navigate routes by click on new post or edit post it fire errors in web console like below.

[image]

**Solution I tried**

1) Remove `javascript_include_tag` from `application.html.erb`. But it will remove turbolink. I don't want to remove that.

2) Restore `javascript_include_tag` and update `index.ts` under `app/javascript/hello-angular/index.ts`. Add turbolink load event as per this video instruction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGToT9RyDxc

**Index.ts**

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
})
```

Work fine. It will render code fine but still same zone error in web console.

[image]

May be this is rails issue. If so then I hope it will resolve in next patch release.

Can any one help that how to resolve this issue ? What I am doing wrong.